# Evaluating javascript using a java code

Tags: java, javascript, web

This might not be practical, but I have it as a task.
I have an opened ServerSocket in java. Now I want to read a file which contains html and javascript, and output the javascript result to the browser. So this way, I would be evaluating the javascript on the server side. So I want what is inside 
to be evaluated.

I tried this to test, it worked but it has some issues, for example it prints the message to System.out. And engine.eval("print('Welocme to java worldddd')"); does not return a String so that I can output it to the outputstream of the socket:

```
import javax.script.*;
// create a script engine manager
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
// create a JavaScript engine
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
try {
     // evaluate JavaScript code from String
     engine.eval("print('Welocme to java worldddd')");
     //engine.eval("a");
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(doComms.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Because `print()` prints to a printer?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571/Java-to-JavaScript-Communication

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the output of the script (what is printed with `print()` in JavaScript) by setting the writer on the `ScriptContext`:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
ScriptContext context = engine.getContext();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
context.setWriter(writer);

engine.eval("print('Welocme to java worldddd')");

String output = writer.toString();

System.out.println("Script output: " + output);
```

Answer (score 7):

I've solved this in the past by creating a javascript function inside `eval()` and invoking it to get a result:

```
import javax.script.*;
// create a script engine manager
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
// create a JavaScript engine
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
try {
     // evaluate JavaScript code from String
     engine.eval("function sum(a,b){ return a + b;}");
     System.out.println(((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("sum", new Object[]{10,20}));
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(doComms.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Note that the function name in `invokeFunction` (first argument) should match the one declared previously.

Keep in mind that this might be dangerous. Do you have absolute control as to where the javascript code comes from? Otherwise a simple `while(true){}` could be pretty catastrophic for your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convertEnumToJson(Class<? extends Enum<?>> cls) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> map = createMap(Colors.class);
    return createJson(map);
}

public static List<Map<String, Object>> createMap(Class<? extends Enum<?>> cls) throws IllegalAccessException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Enum<?> item : cls.getEnumConstants()) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Field field : item.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getType() != item.getClass() && !"$VALUES".equals(field.getName())) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                map.put(field.getName(), field.get(item));
            }
        }

        res.add(map);
    }

    return res;
}

// It's better to use Jackson or similar lib for read/write json
public static <T> String createJson(T obj) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.eval("function sum(a){ return a;}");
    return ((Invocable)engine).invokeFunction("sum", obj).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles upon this page recently like I did, please note that Nashorn has been deprecated according to [this](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/js/NashornMigrationGuide/#:%7E:text=The%20Nashorn%20engine%20has%20been,JavaScript%20previously%20provided%20by%20Nashorn.).

There are other [alternatives](https://jaxenter.com/nashorn-deprecation-interview-caldwell-146951.html) available that you can explore.