# test a boolean expression in string format

Tags: java, boolean

I want to develop a class/method that takes as input a string of this format: `"((true | false) & (!false & false))"`, and returns `true` or `false`, accordingly (in this case `false`).

How should I proceed?

Comment: So you want to take a boolean expression in the form of a string and parse it?

Comment: Yepp, basically that.

Comment: Note that this is bitwise boolean evaluation. Boolean `AND` and `OR` are represented by `&&` and `||` respectively.

Comment: You're totally right, but in this case, I am interested in a regular AND/OR evaluation. But, yes to be correct I have to change the symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if performance is not the issue **AND** you're really sure that the boolean expression is safe (security reasons), you can launch a full-blown JavaScript engine and evaluate the expression

like described in [the following question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787748/evaluating-javascript-using-a-java-code)

Comment: And [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917878/evaluate-string-as-a-condition-java) another good example

Comment: Thank you Funtik! Actually I guess the performance will be an issue, for me. Adding just a small note, that might complicate a bit the problem, is that I am going to implement this in Salesforce(I don't know if you're familiar with), that uses Apex as the propietary language. 
Apex, is a Java-like language, and I thought that I could get a solution adaptable to Apex, but I appreciate your answer, so thank you. :)