# How to convert a string that contains an asterisk to an integer?

Tags: java, string-parsing

I have a string

```
String numAsString = "8 * 9";
```

And I want to convert this into an integer, so when I print the integer

```
int numAsInt = (the code I am asking for);
System.out.println(numAsInt);
```

The output would be

```
72
```

I have tried parseInt and valueOf, but both give an exception cause of the asterisk.
If you don't know, the asterisk means multiplication.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use something like this and it is easy:

```
String[] values = numAsString.split("\\*");
numAsInt = Integer.valueOf(values[0].trim()) * Integer.valueOf(values[1].trim());
```

but If you have a calculation or something with parenthesis, plus, minus and etc, you can use this: 
[Running JavaScript code in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787748/evaluating-javascript-using-a-java-code)
I think this help you.

Comment: You might want to check to see if your example actually works.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I write it without IDE but I forget about special meaning of * in regex

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I'm fine with this because I am not using parentheses.

Comment: For some reason, when I have the variables stated at the very top and then I use them in a function, it gives me a NullPointerException. How can I fix this? And what causes it?

Comment: @AwesomeMaster can you explain more? is it related to this question too?

Comment: Yes it is related. When I say the variables, I mean the code you gave me there. The String array and the numAsInt code.

Comment: Currently I am using @Rahim code while waiting for your response.

Comment: does your input in format "9 * 8" with spaces? if not this doesn't work. I change it to work for "9*8" too. `trim()` will remove space from beginning and end of string.

Comment: Yes, my input has spaces in it.

Comment: so with my edit, which much same as @Rahim , now it works for handling spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Parse string by asterisk and multiply parts:

```
String input = "8 * 9";
String parts[] = input.split("\\*");
int result = 1;
for(String part : parts)
    result *= Integer.parseInt(part.trim());
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.

Comment: Your welcom :) isn’t acceptable?!

Comment: ?? What do you mean, isn't acceptable?